# Bitmap over Wi-Fi best size

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays, android-wifi

i am developing an application which can send camera frames and audio recorded from one android mobile to another 
using UDP with DatagramPacket class 
I've managed to send the recorded audio and playing it on the other side
also I've managed to capture Camera Frames through

```
    Camera.PreviewCallback previewCalBac = new PreviewCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            if (data != null) {
//              mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                Log.d("CAMERA", "CHANGED" + data.length);
                startStreamingVideo(data);
            }
        }
    };
```

and the sending operation is like this

```
private void startStreamingVideo(byte[] data) {
        Log.d(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG, "Starting the video stream");
        if(data!=null){
        currentlySendingVideo = true;
        startVStreaming(data);}
        else{
            Log.d(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG, "NULL DATA");
        }
    }

    private void startVStreaming(final byte[] data) {
        Log.d(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG,
                "Starting the background thread to stream the video data");
        Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.d(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG, "Creating the datagram socket");
                    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                    Log.d(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG, "Creating the buffer of size "+ data.length);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    Log.d(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG, "Connecting to "+ ipAddress.getText().toString() + ":" + VPORT);
                    final InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress.getText().toString());
                    Log.d(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG, "Connected to "+ ipAddress.getText().toString() + ":" + VPORT);
                    Log.d(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG,"Creating the reuseable DatagramPacket");
                    DatagramPacket packet;
                    Log.d(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG, "Creating the VideoRecord");
//                  recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,RECORDING_RATE, CHANNEL, FORMAT, data.length);
//                  Log.d(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG, "VideoRecord recording...");
//                  recorder.startRecording();
                    while (currentlySendingVideo == true) {
                        // read the data into the buffer
                        Log.d(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG, "Here0");
//                      int read = recorder.read(data, 0, data.length);
                        Log.d(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG, "Here");
                        // place contents of buffer into the packet
                        packet = new DatagramPacket(data, 4096,serverAddress, VPORT);
                        Log.d(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG, "Here1");
                        // send the packet
                        socket.send(packet);
                        Log.d(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG, "Here2");
                    }
                    Log.d(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG, "VideoRecord finished recording");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(VIDEO_CLIENT_TAG, "HERE Exception: " + e);
                }
            }
        });
        // start the thread
        streamThread.start();
    }
```

the server side i can get to know that i am receiving the packets
the problem is that the bitmap image byte[] is too big to be sent 
i need to scale it to the best size so i can transfer it and receive it with the least amount of wasted bytes.
any solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you already looked into compressing the data to be transferred, i.e. encoding the video/audio.

Comment: no i haven' tried something like that.
and as I said before U have no problem with the audio
its separated thing
the problem is with the image
how can i compress it?

Comment: Take a look at [setPreviewFormat()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFormat%28int%29) for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Not with UDP, no.  You need a protocol on top of UDP to handle messages>64K.  There is no alternative.

Comment: if the image is scaled and made as smaller size i don't have a problem